# Google Forms - Grid Entry possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a workflow built using Google Forms which currently asks the user which services are required with Yes/No radio buttons.

```
Electrical:     O YES    O NO
Survey:         O YES    O NO
```

I would love if I could change the Yes/No responses into text entry for "number of months" and "cost" So the user can enter beside electrical, '2' for number of months and 10000 for cost, for example. Is there any elegant way to do this or am I stuck having 12 text boxes inline? I guess I could build a custom web app with html for entry, but I'd rather not start from scratch. Ideas? Am I missing something with Google Forms?

Comment: Refer this help [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item). You can not do the way you want with grid items in form, you will have to create 12 radio buttons inline. Web app will be better idea for your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box not available yet.

See also: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2HFVKlsn2rQ

Google Product Forum since 2013, since April 2015 notified to Product team.

> Please add your vote there to push this topic.